# Merging same query parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a URL like so:

https://com.pagehost.co.uk?form=overall&stat1=o35_potential&league=UEFA_Euro_Championship&league=CAF_Confederations_Cup&league=Ligue_2

But there are multiple &league

I want to make it like this instead:

https://com.pagehost.co.uk?form=overall&stat1=o35_potential&league=UEFA_Euro_Championship,CAF_Confederations_Cup,Ligue_2

This is an AJAX request to PHP file, so I could split the , and check all leagues.

Any ideas on how to turn duplicate query parameters into commas?

Comment: It is on your server which one is considered as the value of the parameter. However you can of course merge them but this might lead to **HTTP Parameter Pollution** vulnerability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you need

```js
let url = new URL('https://com.pagehost.co.uk?form=overall&stat1=o35_potential&league=UEFA_Euro_Championship&league=CAF_Confederations_Cup&league=Ligue_2');

url.searchParams.set('league', url.searchParams.getAll('league').join(','));

let updatedUrl = url.toString(); // https://com.pagehost.co.uk/?form=overall&stat1=o35_potential&league=UEFA_Euro_Championship%2CCAF_Confederations_Cup%2CLigue_2
```

`,` is not URL safe character, so it will need to be escaped (hence changed to `%2C`)

Comment: This worked, but if I don't select a league, it leaves it as &league= (empty) I have checked if the paramter is empty in PHP to resolve this but would be better if it didn't add empty paramters.

Comment: Thanks though, saved me a lto of time

Comment: @Oxeem you can check if `url.searchParams.getAll('league').length > 0` before setting search param. Also I am guessing from the line `but if I don't select a league` you are constructing the URL, if that is the case you can directly use `new URLSearchParams({ key: ['1', '2'] }).toString();`
notice  key has array parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This question is not marked as PHP, but it seems like you're asking how to utilize the query data when it's sent comma delimited.

Here's how you can capture those values in PHP and utilize in a prepared mySql statement...

```
<?php
$leagues  = explode(",", $_GET['leagues']); //turns it into an array
// creates a string containing ?,?,? 
$clause = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($leagues), '?'));
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM somewhere WHERE `leagueName` IN (' . $clause . ') ORDER BY `leagueName`;');
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $leagues);
$stmt->execute();
```